# Add CSS to XSL file according to the data value

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have a XSLT file which displays a XML file into a HTML page. There are three tables, I want the data which is greater than -2 under the `maxtemp` column to have a green text-color. I tried the `<xsl:when>`, but it does not work. Can anybody kindly help me with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="weatherdata.xsl"?>
<weatherdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-1" location="Calgary">
        <maxtemp>1.1°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-6.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-2" location="Calgary">
        <maxtemp>-3.4°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-18.2°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>5cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-1-3" location="Calgary">
        <maxtemp>-18.1°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-21.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>1.6cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-01" location="Charlottetown">
        <maxtemp>-3.5°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-15°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0.4cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-02" location="Charlottetown">
        <maxtemp>-1°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-13.2°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0.6cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-03" location="Charlottetown">
        <maxtemp>-11.8°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-16.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>   
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-01" location="Ottawa">
        <maxtemp>-3°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-8.1°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0.2cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-02" location="Ottawa">
        <maxtemp>-3.8°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-15.8°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>0cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
    <stationdata weatherdate="2015-01-03" location="Ottawa">
        <maxtemp>-9.6°C</maxtemp>
        <mintemp>-15.5°C</mintemp>
        <totalrain>0 mm</totalrain>
        <totalsnow>18cm</totalsnow>
    </stationdata>
</weatherdata>
```

This is my XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="thead">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Maximum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Minimum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
        <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
    </tr>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="weatherdata">
    <html align="center">
        <head>
            <title>weather data</title>
            <style type="text/css">

        table, th, td {
       border: 1px solid black;
            }

          th{
          background-color:green;
          }      

 </style>

        </head>
        <body>
       <ul align="left" id="top">
       <li><a href="#Calgary">Calgary Weather</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Charlottetown">Charlottetown Weather</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Ottawa">Ottawa Weather</a></li>
       </ul>

            <h1 id="Calgary">Calgary – Meteorological Data (2015)</h1>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Calgary']"/>
            </table>
            <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>

            <h1 id="Charlottetown">Charlottetown – Meteorological Data (2015)</h1>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Charlottetown']"/>
            </table>

             <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>


            <h1 id="Ottawa">Ottawa – Meteorological Data (2015)</h1>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Ottawa']"/>
            </table>
             <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stationdata">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@weatherdate"/></td>
                <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="maxtemp &gt;'10'">
            <td color="yellow">
            <xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>  
        <td> <xsl:value-of select="mintemp"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="totalrain"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="totalsnow"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your XML above because it wasn't well-formed. Concerning the problem of the comparison of `maxtemp`:

```
<xsl:when test="maxtemp &gt;'10'">
```

did compare `-4.2°C`, a string, to `-2.0`, a number. Which always evaluates to false. So remove the `°C` first and then compare the numbers. I also added a `class` to the CSS part to color it green.

```
<xsl:when test="substring-before(maxtemp, '°C') &gt; -2.0">
  <td class="Warmer">
    ...
```

Here is the complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="thead">
    <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Maximum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Minimum Temperature(°C)</th>
        <th>Total Rain(mm)</th>
        <th>Total Snow(cm)</th>
    </tr>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="weatherdata">
    <html align="center">
        <head>
            <title>weather data</title>
            <style type="text/css">
              table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
              }
              th{
                background-color:green;
              }  
             .Warmer { background-color: GreenYellow;  }
 </style>

        </head>
        <body>
       <ul align="left" id="top">
       <li><a href="#Calgary">Calgary Weather</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Charlottetown">Charlottetown Weather</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Ottawa">Ottawa Weather</a></li>
       </ul>

            <h1 id="Calgary">Calgary – Meteorological Data (2015)</h1>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Calgary']"/>
            </table>
            <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>

            <h1 id="Charlottetown">Charlottetown – Meteorological Data (2015)</h1>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Charlottetown']"/>
            </table>

             <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>


            <h1 id="Ottawa">Ottawa – Meteorological Data (2015)</h1>
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="stationdata[@location='Ottawa']"/>
            </table>
             <a href="#top">Back To Top</a>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stationdata">
    <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@weatherdate"/></td>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="substring-before(maxtemp, '°C') &gt; -2.0">
              <td class="Warmer">
              <xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="maxtemp"/></td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>  
          <td> <xsl:value-of select="mintemp"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="totalrain"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="totalsnow"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you @zx485, You make the point that I`m compare a string to number, I found substring-before(maxtemp, '°C'), I used number() the convert it to a munger , now everything works